# XMLHttpRequest failed: {statusText":Not Found","status::404,"responseURL":https://api.parse.com/1/users" Ionic + Parse

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have been trying to work this out for a while now. I have been working on an ionic + parse login,register,forgot password app. That being said Ionic is the front end and parse.com as the database.

The functions work perfectly from local host in the web broswer when using Ionic serve from command line, but when I build the app for android (ionic build android) or emulate (ionic emulate android) or test it on on an android device I get a range of error messages:

When I attempt to login in; An unexpected error has occurred please try again

when I attempt to reset my password; An unexpected error has occurred please try again

When I attempt to register I am shown this error message:

XMLHttpRequest failed: {statusText":Not     Found","status::404,"responseURL":https://api.parse.com/1/users","response":""resp    onseType":""."responseXML":null,"responseText":"","upload":{loadend":null,"onload":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,"onloadend":null,:onload":null,"onerror":null"onabort":null},"withCredentials":false,"readyState":4"timeout":0,"ontimeout":null,"onprogress":null,"onloadstart":null,:onloadend":null,"onload":null,"onerror":null,:onabort":null}

Here is my code:

**Register page**:template folder

```
<ion-view title="Register">
    <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true" padding="true">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="First Name">
  </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Date of Birth</span>
                <input type="date" ng-model="user.dob">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="assertive" ng-show="error.message">{{error.message}}</div>
        <button class="button button-block button-stable" ng-click="register()">
            CREATE ACCOUNT
        </button>
        By creating an account you agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy.
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('ionicParseApp.controllers', [])
.controller('AppController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $stateParams) {
    if ($stateParams.clear) {
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    }
    $scope.logout = function() {
        Parse.User.logOut();
        $rootScope.user = null;
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
        $state.go('welcome', {
            clear: true
        });
    };
})
.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $stateParams) {
    if ($stateParams.clear) {
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    }
    $scope.login = function() {
        $state.go('app.login');
    };
    $scope.signUp = function() {
        $state.go('app.register');
    };
    if ($rootScope.isLoggedIn) {
        $state.go('app.home');
    }
})
.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope) {
    if (!$rootScope.isLoggedIn) {
        $state.go('welcome');
    }
})
.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.user = {
        username: null,
        password: null
    };
    $scope.error = {};
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Logging in',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });
        var user = $scope.user;
        Parse.User.logIn(('' + user.username).toLowerCase(), user.password, {
            success: function(user) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $rootScope.user = user;
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                $state.go('app.home', {
                    clear: true
                });
            },
            error: function(user, err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                if (err.code === 101) {
                    $scope.error.message = 'Invalid login credentials';
                } else {
                    $scope.error.message = 'An unexpected error has ' +
                        'occurred, please try again.';
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.forgot = function() {
        $state.go('app.forgot');
    };
})
.controller('ForgotPasswordController', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.error = {};
    $scope.state = {
        success: false
    };
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Sending',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });
        Parse.User.requestPasswordReset($scope.user.email, {
            success: function() {
                // TODO: show success
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $scope.state.success = true;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                if (err.code === 125) {
                    $scope.error.message = 'Email address does not exist';
                } else {
                    $scope.error.message = 'An unknown error has occurred, ' +
                        'please try again';
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
        $state.go('app.login');
    };
})
.controller('RegisterController', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, $rootScope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.error = {};
    $scope.register = function() {
        // TODO: add age verification step
        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Sending',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });
        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("username", $scope.user.email);
        user.set("password", $scope.user.password);
        user.set("email", $scope.user.email);
        user.signUp(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $rootScope.user = user;
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                $state.go('app.home', {
                    clear: true
                });
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                if (error.code === 125) {
                    $scope.error.message = 'Please specify a valid email ' +
                        'address';
                } else if (error.code === 202) {
                    $scope.error.message = 'The email address is already ' +
                        'registered';
                } else {
                    $scope.error.message = error.message;
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
})
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory) {
    if ($stateParams.clear) {
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    }
    $scope.rightButtons = [{
        type: 'button-positive',
        content: '<i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>',
        tap: function(e) {
            $scope.sideMenuController.toggleRight();
        }
    }];
    $scope.logout = function() {
        Parse.User.logOut();
        $rootScope.user = null;
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
        $state.go('welcome', {
            clear: true
        });
    };
    $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
        $scope.sideMenuController.toggleRight();
    };
});
```

**apps.js**

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
            .state('welcome', {
                url: '/welcome?clear',
                templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
                controller: 'WelcomeController'
            })

            .state('app', {
                url: '/app?clear',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
                controller: 'AppController'
            })

            .state('app.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.login', {
                url: '/login',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                        controller: 'LoginController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.forgot', {
                url: '/forgot',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/forgotPassword.html',
                        controller: 'ForgotPasswordController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('app.register', {
                url: '/register',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
                        controller: 'RegisterController'
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
    })
    .run(function ($state, $rootScope) {
        Parse.initialize('**hidden**', '**hidden**');
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        $rootScope.user = null;
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;

        if (currentUser) {
            $rootScope.user = currentUser;
            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
            $state.go('app.home');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably cause you must add the plugin [whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

if you want to save the reference to your config.xml file:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

You should have this:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in your **config.xml** file. If you go trough the specs of the [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) you will [see](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#network-request-whitelist) you can white-list your domain or external domains.
Leaving it like that means you're white-listing everything: all the requests.

Some of these features have been introduced by the new cordova version.
Some more info [here](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/).

If you want to see what's exactly causing troubles with your app I would suggest you to plug your android device to your computer via USB, activate the debugging features and use Chrome as an inspector visiting this [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) in your browser.

You should be able to see your device attached and debug it as you would with a standard web application.

Comment: i have never used the whitelist plugin in a ionic application using parse, this may work... but i am not certain it is required.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Finally I able able to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: @user2993476: You should accept the answer instead of answering your own question with a "thank you". cheers.

Comment: I second the answer. My app was working fine until i updated ionic/cordova. This suggestion resolved my issue.